# How do I filter date range in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, datetime, filter, datatables

I have a large dataTable which contains ride information. Every row has a start datetime and an end datetime of the following format(yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss). How can I use a datepicker for setting a filter range in dataTables? I want to have a datepicker which only selects a day and not the time. I've searched everywhere for the proper answer but I couldn't find it.

For example I want to see all rows of July by selecting (01-07-2016 - 31-07-2016).

Comment: The accepted answer has a lot of distracting fluff. The simple answer is that you need to push a filter callback onto the `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` array. [See the documentation for more info.](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is `DataTable` with Single `DatePicker` as "from" Date Filter

<kbd>[LiveDemo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8z7cojpJoCSJXRn9prNj?p=preview)</kbd>

Here is `DataTable` with Two `DatePickers` for DateRange (To and From) Filter

<kbd>[LiveDemo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdeEYoZtnvpfHCdtSxDP?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I wonder if this also works with my current configuration of my dataTable. I have already two filters for the column with license plates and one filter for the column with the personal ID's. Besides that I implemented the export functions(tabletools) of dataTables. [link]https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28077/disable-filtering-of-one-or-multiple-columns-select-inputs and [link]https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/ are already implemented.

Comment: Yes they will work because this `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` is api for DataTable.

Comment: ***[Here](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)*** is another example for your understanding..

Comment: The informations has been very useful for me. I am almost there. The last thing that needs to be solved is the refreshment of the table after selecting the date. The datepicker is good connected because, the correct data is shown after choosing one of the other filters. The oTable.fnDraw(); function should update the table but it doesn't. Here is the javaScript http://pastebin.com/SjDQQzJ7

Comment: please check your browser console. is there any error?

Comment: The filter works, but the table only show the result after choosing/updating one of the two column filters(0,1) from the initComplete function.

Comment: can you post your datatable initialization script?

Comment: Problem solved. oTable.draw(); instead of oTable.fnDraw(); fixed the problem.

Comment: @mmushtaq , thank you for this solution. However, if I have two columns with date, can I also choose from which column to filter the data.

Comment: @rahim.nagori - yes, you can. `aData` contains the table row values. `aData._date1 = new Date(aData[6]).getTime();` So you have to specify which index you need to consider. and adjust the `if ()` according to your requirements

Answer (score 14):

Here is my solution, cobbled together from the range filter example in the [datatables docs](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html), and letting [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) do the dirty work of comparing the dates.

## HTML

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="min-date"
    class="date-range-filter"
    placeholder="From: yyyy-mm-dd">

<input 
    type="text" 
    id="max-date" 
    class="date-range-filter"
    placeholder="To: yyyy-mm-dd">

<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

## JS

Install Moment: `npm install moment`

```
// Assign moment to global namespace
window.moment = require('moment');

// Set up your table
table = $('#my-table').DataTable({
    // ... do your thing here.
});

// Extend dataTables search
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min  = $('#min-date').val();
        var max  = $('#max-date').val();
        var createdAt = data[2] || 0; // Our date column in the table

        if  ( 
                ( min == "" || max == "" )
                || 
                ( moment(createdAt).isSameOrAfter(min) && moment(createdAt).isSameOrBefore(max) ) 
            )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);

// Re-draw the table when the a date range filter changes
$('.date-range-filter').change( function() {
    table.draw();
} );
```

### [JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cjedgerton/hkoqbaex/1/)

## Notes

- Using moment decouples the date comparison logic, and makes it easy to work with different formats. In my table, I used `yyyy-mm-dd`, but you could use `mm/dd/yyyy` as well. Be sure to reference [moment's docs when parsing other formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), as you may need to modify what method you use.

Comment: I am having troubling in converting it to type bases plugin instead of row based https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972802/datatables-type-based-plugin

Comment: Hi django, the url to the question you posted is invalid. What trouble are you having?

Comment: i am troubling to use moment js in my script.

Comment: works fine for client side datatables rendering. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason moment.before didnt work so I just did the dirty work myself and it works well. thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to speed up the redraw process?

Answer (score 4):

```js
 $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var FilterStart = $('#filter_From').val();
        var FilterEnd = $('#filter_To').val();
        var DataTableStart = data[4].trim();
        var DataTableEnd = data[5].trim();
        if (FilterStart == '' || FilterEnd == '') {
            return true;
        }
        if (DataTableStart >= FilterStart && DataTableEnd <= FilterEnd)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        
    });
    --------------------------
 $('#filter_From').change(function (e) {
        Table.draw();

    });
    $('#filter_To').change(function (e) {
          Table.draw();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, there is no way to use momemt.js.Here is DataTable with Two DatePickers for DateRange (To and From) Filter.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
    var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
    var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
    if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
    if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
    if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
    if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
    return false;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using other posters code with some tweaks:

```
<table id="MainContent_tbFilterAsp" style="margin-top:-15px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:initial;"><label for="datepicker_from" id="MainContent_datepicker_from_lbl" style="margin-top:7px;">From date:</label>&nbsp;
                </td>
                
                <td style="padding-right: 20px;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$datepicker_from" type="text" id="datepicker_from" class="datepick form-control hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off" style="cursor:pointer; background-color: #FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
                
                <td style="vertical-align:initial"><label for="datepicker_to" id="MainContent_datepicker_to_lbl" style="margin-top:7px;">To date:</label>&nbsp;
                </td>
                
                <td style="padding-right: 20px;"><input name="ctl00$MainContent$datepicker_to" type="text" id="datepicker_to" class="datepick form-control hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off" style="cursor:pointer; background-color: #FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                        
                </td>
                
                <td style="vertical-align:initial"><a onclick="$('#datepicker_from').val(''); $('#datepicker_to').val(''); return false;" id="datepicker_clear_lnk" style="margin-top:7px;">Clear</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
                var oTable = $('#tbAD').DataTable({
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Filter Data"
                },
                "iDisplayLength": -1,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "pageLength": 50, 
                });

                $("#datepicker_from").datepicker();
                $("#datepicker_to").datepicker();

                $('#datepicker_from').change(function (e) {
                    oTable.draw();
                });
                $('#datepicker_to').change(function (e) {
                    oTable.draw();
                });
                $('#datepicker_clear_lnk').click(function (e) {
                    oTable.draw();
                });
            });   

            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                var min = $('#datepicker_from').datepicker("getDate") == null ? null : $('#datepicker_from').datepicker("getDate").setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var max = $('#datepicker_to').datepicker("getDate") == null ? null : $('#datepicker_to').datepicker("getDate").setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var startDate = new Date(data[9]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
                if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
                if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
                if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
                if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }                    
                return false;
                }
            );
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following one is working fine with moments js 2.10 and above

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            var min  = $('#min-date').val()
            var max  = $('#max-date').val()
            var createdAt = data[0] || 0; // Our date column in the table
            //createdAt=createdAt.split(" ");
            var startDate   = moment(min, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            var endDate     = moment(max, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            var diffDate = moment(createdAt, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            //console.log(startDate);
            if (
              (min == "" || max == "") ||
              (diffDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate))


            ) {  return true;  }
            return false;

        }
    );
```

Comment: `var endDate     = moment(max).add('1','days');` If you want the date to be inclusive.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the link below and configure it to what you need. Daterangepicker does it for you, very easily. :)

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex1