# date range filter in datatable with server side processing

Tags: jquery, datatables

So, I have a basic datable with three columns - `type`, `amount`, `added_at`.

I want to apply date range filter on `added_at` column with server side processing.

I've looked into this following posts:
[How do I filter date range in DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717543/how-do-i-filter-date-range-in-datatables)

And also this: http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

But I am not able to integrate this with server side. What changes do I need to make in javascript to get the data from server. My current setup already gets the data from server.

```
$("#transactions").dataTable({
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : transactionUrl,
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "simple_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "searching" : false,
        "ordering" : true,
        "info" : false,
        "aoColumns" : [{
          "mData" : "type"
        }, {
          "mData": "amount"
        }, {
          "mData" : "added_at",
          "render": function (data) {
            return getDate(data);
          }
        }],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
          "defaultContent": "-",
          "targets": "_all"
        }]
      });
    });
```

I tried this after suggestion in comment.

Added this to datatable-

```
"ajax": {
          "url": transactionUrl,
          "data": {
            "date_from": daterange_from,
            "date_to": daterange_to
          }
        }
```

`daterange_from` and `daterange_to` is the global variable, which is empty initially and is set after the date is selected in the callback function of daterangepicker.

removed sAjaxSource from previous code.

And added this daterange picker

```
$('input[name="datepicker_range"]').daterangepicker(
              {
                locale: {
                  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                },
                autoUpdateInput: true
              },
              function (start, end, label) {
                $("#datepicker_from").val(getDate(start));
                $("#datepicker_to").val(getDate(end));
                console.log($("#datepicker_from").val());
                console.log($("#datepicker_to").val());
                daterange_from = document.getElementById("datepicker_from").value;
                daterange_to = document.getElementById("datepicker_to").value;
                console.log(label);
                oTable.fnDestroy();
                oTable.fnDraw();
              });
```

Now the issue is I get the value of

Comment: Since you already have a way to read your date filter, you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867940/how-to-implement-pagination-with-serverside-get-api-in-datatables/48898762#48898762 to get data from server by passing it to your API

Comment: It didn't work. In ajax.data, I set the date_from and date_to, and it is always empty when datatable makes an ajax call after I change the date. 
I can post the updated code.

Comment: Read it directly from elements rather than variables.. I mean $( appropriatedatepickerid).val() in your ajax.

Comment: I tried that too. It didn't work.

Comment: Did you check $("#datepicker_from").val() is the right way to get data for your datepicker?